# Spring boot wep application to IBM Websphere

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, websphere-7

I have created the Web application(Spring MVC) using  spring boot and executed it via in-build server apache tomcat( maven tomcat plugin). it is working fine.  So my question is how to deploy this WAR into WAS 7.0 application server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change packaging in Maven to WAR and define deployment descriptor. [Read this section if Spring Boot reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

Comment: WebSphere 7 is only Java EE 5, so it's a Servlet 2.5 application server. That makes it a bit more difficult. The extra steps required are [described in the reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-servlet-2-5)

Comment: Thanks Iuboskmac and Andy. I will check it.